# Bluetooth app crashed due to ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I trying to connect my bluetooth device using the bluetooth code sample. But after it said connected with bluetooth then the app crashed. Here are the error:

```
2-28 15:30:54.550    8431-8431/course.examples.healthapp E/ArrayAdapter? You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
12-28 15:30:54.560    8431-8431/course.examples.healthapp D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
12-28 15:30:54.560    8431-8431/course.examples.healthapp E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: course.examples.healthapp, PID: 8431
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Here are my source files (Dropbox):

[Bluetooth Data display](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c2y7qx4u9tw9bn/BluetoothData_display.txt?dl=0)

[Bluetooth Service](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqpn40382mks6uy/bluetoothservice.txt?dl=0)

[Device list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1lep2weojlt7sd/devicelist.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Means layout passed to `ArrayAdapter` is not contains TextView as root item

Comment: Ok. Yea I changed the layout now is working.